# Chamando um NodeMailer.js através do Javascript (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível executar um nodemailer via javascript (AJAX).

Pois retorna erro  e não consigo debugar (pois esta no servidor). 

Este é o jeito certo de chamar o arquivo? 

Obrigado

O código de NodeMailer.js

```js
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "someHost",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "myamail@something.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Você" <email@something.com>',
    to: "email@email.com",
    subject: "Nodejs - Teste para o tutorial ??",
    text: "O teste foi efectuado com sucesso"
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
    if(err){
        console.log(err); // Não retorna este console
    }else{
        console.log("Mensagem enviada com sucesso"); //Este também não
    }
});
```

E este é o via JavaScript tentando executar o arquivo Node

```js
function enviaEmail() {
    setLoadingBoxDisplay("block");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../scripts/nodeMailer.js",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Sucess");
        },
        complete: function () {
            setLoadingBoxDisplay("none");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Fail");
            //var exc = data.responseJSON;
            //window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Chamando o arquivo diretamente não, você tem que inserir o nodemailer em sua aplicação web, no caso do nodemailer um serviço com nodejs, criar um servidor e uma rota para que sua aplicação de front end possa consumi-la e assim o nodejs se encarrega de mandar o email.

Comment: Como posso inserir o nodemailer em uma aplicação na Web??

Comment: Você está usando node.js? O nodemailer é um modulo dele...

Comment: Sim sim, estou, é o primeiro código postado, vou pesquisar mais sobre aqui

Comment: Então a ideia é que você esteja rodando um serviço com nodejs, crie uma rota e esta rota é que vai ter o nodemailer e a configuração de envio. Ai você manda o seu AJAX requisitar a rota que você criou...

Comment: Entendi, vou testar, obrigado

Comment: Porque o que estou fazendo é, tem um arquivo node no servidor e requisito uma rota até este arquivo do AJAX, porém cai no `console.log` de erro, aparentemente está dando errado

Comment: Você esta fazendo um GET diretamento pro arquivo, e não é pra ele que você deve fazer e sim pra uma rota tipo: /enviar_email nesse caso você configura essa rota em seu serviço web.

Comment: Certo!! dou um retorno em breve, obrigado